# How to reduce length of white dash line so it matches image and text height?

Tags: html, css

UPDATE I've actually seen its the length it is because the .main div is the parent and its sizing to that. I'm not sure how to adjust that...

Trying to reduce the dashed line to match the same height as text, how do I do this?

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/7U7H3/

```
        <div class="container clearfix">

<div class="main">
    <p>
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!
    <p >
    <img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="sky">
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="img/cheese2.jpg" alt="sky" id="img">
    </p>
        <p id="mainb">
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!
    <p>
</div>
```

```
  .main {
     -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
     -webkit-column-rule: 5px dotted #FFF;
     -webkit-columns: 100px 2;
     font-size: 3.5vw;
     text-align: right;
     line-height: 1.0;
   }
 img {
     margin: 1.5em 0;
     max-width: 100%;
    float:left;
  }
```

Comment: `.main p {
    margin: 0;
}`

Comment: Tried a few things with no luck! interesting problem!

Comment: The jsfiddle does not correspond to the code posted, e.g. it has just one `img` tag, and the image is missing. The question use WebKit specific CSS but this is not expressed in the question. There is no dashed line, just a dotted rule.

Comment: your content is too less so its showing you the dotted line greater than the text.Add more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try setting margin for img to a little lesser value and setting margin and padding for all the rest elements to 0.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7U7H3/9/)

Setting

```
img {
       margin: 0.1em 0;
       max-width: 100%;
       float:left;
}
```

Adding this to css

```
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

did the trick for me as of now. But it will all depend on the height of image. After setting this margin property if the height of image is greater than the text than div height will expand and so will the webkit line. This is by far the manual solution to your issue, but there are many other ways of achieving this, just try to change your approach for a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo have a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/PxPMW/

```
  .newspaper
   {
      column-count:3;
      column-gap:40px;
      column-rule:4px dotted #ff00ff;

      /* Firefox */
       -moz-column-count:3;
       -moz-column-gap:40px;
       -moz-column-rule:4px dotted #ff00ff;

       /* Safari and Chrome */
       -webkit-column-count:3;
       -webkit-column-gap:40px;
       -webkit-column-rule:4px dotted #ff00ff;
       }
        img{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
           }
```

Add more content to the div.Till then it won't fix.Adding more content to the div will automatically do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I've actually seen its the length it is because the .main div is the parent and its sizing to that. I'm not sure how to adjust that...